# getting images based on the closest checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get all the images that are closest to the nearest checkboxes that are checked. For instance, say there are three photos and two are checked, I would want to get the closest image to the checkbox (images are above the checkboxes) and put the src of the image into an array with jQuery. However, I am only having luck getting the first image and not the others that are checked. The list of images are dependent on how many images are in the album (fetched from PHP and sent to the page via ajax).

Here is my code:

```
$('.w3-check').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // get the image that is by the check box
        $('.w3-third').find('.w3-card-2, .w3-margin, img.photo').each(function() {
            console.log($('img.photo').attr('src'));
        });
    }
});
```

html -

```
<div class="w3-third" style="width: 32.5%; max-height: 200px;">        
       <div class="w3-card-2 w3-margin">                                 
          <img class="photo" src="/images/profile/fooboy/albums/test album_2017-07-14/downfall-frother.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-height: 150px; padding-bottom: 5px;">                                                     
          <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="delete_downfall-frother.jpg" id="delete_downfall-frother.jpg">                             
          <label for="delete_downfall-frother.jpg">&nbsp;Check to Delete</label>                                                             
       </div>                                                            
       <br>                                                            
</div>


<div class="w3-third" style="width: 32.5%; max-height: 200px;">          
        <div class="w3-card-2 w3-margin">                                    
             <img class="photo" src="/images/profile/fooboy/albums/test album_2017-07-14/crooked.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-height: 150px; padding-bottom: 5px;">                                                             
               <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="delete_crooked.jpg" id="delete_crooked.jpg">                                                   
               <label for="delete_crooked.jpg">&nbsp;Check to Delete</label>
       </div>                                                                
       <br>                                                                
    </div>

    <div class="w3-third" style="width: 32.5%; max-height: 200px;">
         <div class="w3-card-2 w3-margin">
           <img class="photo" src="/images/profile/fooboy/albums/test album_2017-07-14/cref.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-height: 150px; padding-bottom: 5px;">                                                             
               <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="delete_cref.jpg" id="delete_cref.jpg">                                                      
               <label for="delete_cref.jpg">&nbsp;Check to Delete</label>  
         </div>                                                              
        <br>                                                               
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot that may help better explain:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aldka.jpg

As you can see, it is only getting the first image and not the others even though they are checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but this will get you a list of everything that is checked whenever any checkbox is changed.

**edit:** Now with more comments!

```
// Attach an event handler when any check box is changed.
$('.w3-check').on('change', function() {
    var arr = [];
    // Iterate over *all* checked input.w3-check elements inside any element
    // that is both .w3-card-2 and .w3-margin.
    $('.w3-card-2.w3-margin input.w3-check:checked').each(function(index, checkbox) {
      // Get the jQuery representation of the checkbox (second parameter
      // in the each handler).
      var $checkbox = $(checkbox);

      // Get the closest parent of that checkbox that is both
      // .w3-card-2 and .w3-margin.
      var $card = $checkbox.closest(".w3-card-2.w3-margin");

      // Within that parent, find a child that is an img.photo element.
      var $img = $card.find("img.photo");

      // Add the src attribute of that element to the array.
      arr[arr.length] = $img.attr('src');
    });
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/er5cmfdn/), though it obviously doesn't display the images.

**edit:** To explain what's different between the code in the original question and the code in this answer:

```
// This is the same; attach an event handler when a check box changes.
$('.w3-check').on('change', function() {
    // Check to see if the current check box is checked.
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // From within *all* .w3-third elements, find *all*
        // .w3-card-2 elements, all .w3-margins elements, and
        // all img.photo elements and iterate over them.
        $('.w3-third').find('.w3-card-2, .w3-margin, img.photo').each(function() {
            // For each element matching that condition,
            // find *all* img.photo elements in the entire page, since
            // $(selector) searches the whole page, then get the src
            // attribute of the first match since attr doesn't return
            // a result for each item in the jQuery result set.
            console.log($('img.photo').attr('src'));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm uploading a snippet here that you can see the result as well.

[**Here it is.**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=aa4f4c2a3d74d6fb4ff6f13fe6a453dd)

I'm counting the number of checkboxes and do a loop for each of them to check if they are checked and if yes get the src val into an array called "photoarray"

Answer (score 0):

You can just look for the parent and find the image with class photo.

```
var images = [];
$('.w3-check').on('change', function() {
    var src = $(this).parent().find('img.photo').attr('src');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // get the image that is by the check box
        images.push(src);
    } else {
        images.splice(images.indexOf(src), 1);
    }
    console.log(images);
});
```